# NodeJS: How can I create a fake tcp socket for testing servers

Tags: node.js, sockets, unit-testing, stream, mocking

I'm trying to unit test my server code (non-http, custom protocol). I need to create a mock duplex socket that I can send messages to asynchronously and receive messages from.

I've had some marginal success creating a duplex stream from event-stream readArray and writeArray, but readArray requires having the data up front, and writeArray doesn't fire until the stream ends. I need to test over time.  An ideal solution would be two duplex sockets linked together.

Are there any existing solutions for this? I'd rather not have to resort to initializing an actual server to test this.

Comment: [node-mitm](https://github.com/moll/node-mitm) may help you.

Comment: node-mitm is for capturing outgoing requests.  I'm trying to simulate an incoming request.

Answer (score 2):

[Node Mitm](https://github.com/moll/node-mitm) can actually do that just fine. It can intercept and mock not only HTTP but any TCP connection.

```js
mitm.on("connection", function(socket) { socket.write("Hello back!") })

var socket = Net.connect(22, "example.org")
socket.write("Hello!")
socket.setEncoding("utf8")
socket.read() // => "Hello back!"
```

Comment: I'm not trying to intercept an incoming connection, I'm not trying to intercept anything at all. I want to create a mock tcp connection to pass into my connection handler (the function that you provide to net.createServer) and other functions, which I can then communicate over in a testable manner without having to launc an actual server.

Comment: Then you might want to have a look at this : [https://gist.github.com/FGRibreau/7284395](https://gist.github.com/FGRibreau/7284395)

Comment: Yes, I found that in my searching. It's not pipe-able, which makes it unusable with my test case. I need a working stream, not just an emulation of one, and I don't know enough about the streams api to make it do what I need. What I really want is just two duplex streams that are connected to each other, but I can't figure out how to make that work.